# Stop the Pandoc R package from adding line breaks

Tags: r, pandoc

I'm using the [Pandoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandoc) package in R to change a [.docx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) file to HTML:

```
message = pandoc::pandoc_convert(file="message.docx",from = "docx", to = "HTML")
```

The resulting HTML has linefeeds, "\n\r"

Can I prevent this?

Comment: Please share message.docx file

Comment: On [Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Windows), presumably? What ***versions*** (incl. edition for Windows, e.g. '[Home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_editions#Baseline_editions)') of Pandoc, the Pandoc package, R, and Windows?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, make sure you have installed the latest version of pandoc package. If you install by `install.packages("pandoc")`, by default it installs latest version. But if you have installed pandoc and you want to install another version, you can use below code:

```
library(pandoc)
# Current latest version is 3.1.1
pandoc_install("3.1.1")
```

Then you can use below code to convert .docx file to .html file:

```
library(pandoc)
#pandoc_version()    # latest version currently is ‘3.1.1’

message = pandoc::pandoc_convert(file="C:/Users/LENOVO.PIESC/Desktop/R-Intro.docx",
                                 from = "docx", to = "HTML")

message   # This shows raw html content

# Apply writeLines function to save raw html content in a html file
writeLines(message, "C:/Users/LENOVO.PIESC/Desktop/test.html")
```

Some valid points:

1. The message variable in your code has the raw html content. I
   used `writeLines()` method to write it into a html file. Make sure to insert full path for .docx and .html files (according to your operating system separators).
2. With latest version of pandoc, there is no \n\r linefeeds and the
   converted html file, perfectly distinguishes headings, ul elements,
   bold characters, etc.
3. If your file includes images, pandoc detects it perfectly and
   creates image tag for it, but clearly, the image tag src/href should
   be change manually in html file, because that image has local
   reference in file system of a Microsoft word document.

I used a sample .docx file as below:

[image]

and the result html file is as this:

[image]

As you see in word file, between first paragraph and Unordered List element, there are couple of line break, but pandoc, smartly doesn't add `<br>` tag in html content for each line break in word document.

Comment: The new .HTML file displays properly in a browser but the linebreaks are still there.  I need to get rid of them.

Comment: .html file displays properly in a browser and there is no line break or <br> tag in .html file. But if you want to get rid from line breaks in your word file (regardless of .html file), you can use Microsoft Word software and it helps you to remove bulk line breaks. If you want to pandoc to remove line breaks from your word file (regardless of .html file), this is another problem which should be investigated through pandoc library if it has some methods for it or not.